# Removing NA when preforming matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I was wondering if there is a better way to omit `NA` when using matrix multiplication.  I'm currently using this approach

```
a <- c(NA,4,3,2)
b <- c(4,3,1,NA)

logic <- !is.na(a) & !is.na(b)

a[logic]%*%b[logic]
```

Was hoping for something like this...

```
`%*%`(a, b, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: You can create a function and reuse it.

Comment: For example `"%*NA%" <- function(x,y){
          if(is.na(x)|| is.na(y)){
           i1 <- !is.na(x) & !is.na(y)
           x[i1] %*% y[i1]
      } else {
             x %*% y
       }
 }` then use `a%*NA%b` if there are no NA values `a1 <- 4:2, b1 <- c(4,3,1); a1%*NA%b1`

Comment: @akrun I believe you need a `;` between `i1 <- !is.na(x) & !is.na(y)` and `x[i1] %*% y[i1]`; as in `i1 <- !is.na(x) & !is.na(y); x[i1] %*% y[i1]`. Of course with all of the code around it.

Comment: @steveb  Yes, I was just copy/pasting my code so as to give the OP some ideas

Comment: @akrun I see, it had newlines prior to copying.